# How to perform orthogonal regression (total least squares) via PCA?

Tags: r, pca, least-squares, deming-regression, total-least-squares

I always use `lm()` in R to perform linear regression of $y$ on $x$. That function returns a coefficient $\beta$ such that $$y = \beta x.$$

Today I learned about **total least squares** and that `princomp()` function (principal component analysis, PCA) can be used to perform it. It should be good for me (more accurate). I have done some tests using `princomp()`, like:

```
r <- princomp( ~ x + y)
```

My problem is: how to interpret its results? How can I get the regression coefficient? By "coefficient" I mean the number $\beta$ that I have to use to multiply the $x$ value to give a number close to $y$.

Comment: One moment guys, i'm a bit confused. look at: http://zoonek2.free.fr/UNIX/48_R/09.html This is called PCA (Principal Component Analysis, aka "orthogonal regression" or "perpendicular sums of squares" or "total least squares") so i think we are talking about TLS with princomp() No?

Comment: No; those are two different things, see wikipedia article about PCA. The fact it is used here is a hack (I don't know how exact, but I'm going to check it); that's why the complex extraction of coefficients.

Comment: A related question: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2691/making-sense-of-principal-component-analysis-eigenvectors-eigenvalues and a blog post is referenced by one of the answers: http://www.cerebralmastication.com/2010/09/principal-component-analysis-pca-vs-ordinary-least-squares-ols-a-visual-explination/

Answer (score 65, accepted):

### Ordinary least squares vs. total least squares

Let's first consider the simplest case of only one predictor (independent) variable $x$. For simplicity, let both $x$ and $y$ be centered, i.e. intercept is always zero. The difference between standard OLS regression and "orthogonal" TLS regression is clearly shown on this (adapted by me) figure from [the most popular answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/2700/28666) in the most popular thread on PCA:

[image: OLS vs TLS]

OLS fits the equation $y=\beta x$ by minimizing squared distances between observed values $y$ and predicted values $\hat y$. TLS fits the same equation by minimizing squared distances between $(x,y)$ points and their projection on the line. In this simplest case TLS line is simply the first principal component of the 2D data. To find $\beta$, do PCA on $(x,y)$ points, i.e. construct the $2\times 2$ covariance matrix $\boldsymbol \Sigma$ and find its first eigenvector $\mathbf v = (v_x, v_y)$;  then $\beta = v_y/v_x$.

In Matlab:

```r
 v = pca([x y]);    //# x and y are centered column vectors
 beta = v(2,1)/v(1,1);
```

In R:

```r
 v <- prcomp(cbind(x,y))$rotation
 beta <- v[2,1]/v[1,1]
```

By the way, this will yield correct slope even if $x$ and $y$ were not centered (because built-in PCA functions automatically perform centering). To recover the intercept, compute $\beta_0 = \bar y - \beta \bar x$.

### OLS vs. TLS, multiple regression

Given a dependent variable $y$ and many independent variables $x_i$ (again, all centered for simplicity), regression fits an equation $$y= \beta_1 x_1 + \ldots + \beta_p x_p.$$ OLS does the fit by minimizing the squared errors between observed values of $y$ and predicted values $\hat y$. TLS does the fit by minimizing the squared distances between observed $(\mathbf x, y)\in\mathbb R^{p+1}$ points and the closest points on the regression plane/hyperplane.

Note that there is no "regression line" anymore! The equation above specifies a *hyperplane*: it's a 2D plane if there are two predictors, 3D hyperplane if there are three predictors, etc. So the solution above does not work: we cannot get the TLS solution by taking the first PC only (which is a line). Still, the solution can be easily obtained via PCA.

As before, PCA is performed on $(\mathbf x, y)$ points. This yields $p+1$ eigenvectors in columns of $\mathbf V$. The first $p$ eigenvectors define a $p$-dimensional hyperplane $\mathcal H$ that we need; the last (number $p+1$) eigenvector $\mathbf v_{p+1}$ is orthogonal to it. The question is how to transform the basis of $\mathcal H$ given by the first $p$ eigenvectors into the $\boldsymbol \beta$ coefficients.

Observe that if we set $x_i=0$ for all $i \ne k$ and only $x_k=1$, then $\hat y=\beta_k$, i.e. the vector $$(0,\ldots, 1, \ldots, \beta_k) \in \mathcal H$$ lies in the hyperplane $\mathcal H$. On the other hand, we know that $$\mathbf v_{p+1}=(v_1, \ldots, v_{p+1}) \:\bot\: \mathcal H$$ is orthogonal to it. I.e. their dot product must be zero: $$v_k + \beta_k v_{p+1}=0 \Rightarrow \beta_k = -v_k/v_{p+1}.$$

In Matlab:

```r
 v = pca([X y]);    //# X is a centered n-times-p matrix, y is n-times-1 column vector
 beta = -v(1:end-1,end)/v(end,end);
```

In R:

```r
 v <- prcomp(cbind(X,y))$rotation
 beta <- -v[-ncol(v),ncol(v)] / v[ncol(v),ncol(v)]
```

Again, this will yield correct slopes even if $x$ and $y$ were not centered (because built-in PCA functions automatically perform centering). To recover the intercept, compute $\beta_0 = \bar y - \bar {\mathbf x} \boldsymbol \beta$.

As a sanity check, notice that this solution coincides with the previous one in case of only a single predictor $x$. Indeed, then the $(x,y)$ space is 2D, and so, given that the first PCA eigenvector is orthogonal to the second (last) one,  $v^{(1)}_y/v^{(1)}_x=-v^{(2)}_x/v^{(2)}_y$.

### Closed form solution for TLS

Surprisingly, it turns out that there is a closed form equation for $\boldsymbol \beta$. The argument below is taken from Sabine van Huffel's book "The total least squares" (section 2.3.2).

Let $\mathbf X$ and $\mathbf y$ be the centered data matrices. The last PCA eigenvector $\mathbf v_{p+1}$ is an eigenvector of the covariance matrix of $[\mathbf X\: \mathbf y]$ with an eigenvalue $\sigma^2_{p+1}$. If it is an eigenvector, then so is $-\mathbf v_{p+1}/v_{p+1} = (\boldsymbol \beta\:\: -1)^\top$. Writing down the eigenvector equation:
$$\left(\begin{array}{c}\mathbf X^\top \mathbf X & \mathbf X^\top \mathbf y\\ \mathbf y^\top \mathbf X &  \mathbf y^\top \mathbf y\end{array}\right) \left(\begin{array}{c}\boldsymbol \beta \\ -1\end{array}\right) = \sigma^2_{p+1}\left(\begin{array}{c}\boldsymbol \beta \\ -1\end{array}\right),$$
and computing the product on the left, we immediately get that $$\boldsymbol \beta_\mathrm{TLS} = (\mathbf X^\top \mathbf X - \sigma^2_{p+1}\mathbf I)^{-1} \mathbf X^\top \mathbf y,$$ which strongly reminds the familiar OLS expression $$\boldsymbol \beta_\mathrm{OLS} = (\mathbf X^\top \mathbf X)^{-1} \mathbf X^\top \mathbf y.$$

### Multivariate multiple regression

The same formula can be generalized to the multivariate case, but even *to define* what multivariate TLS does, would require some algebra. [See Wikipedia on TLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_least_squares#Algebraic_point_of_view). Multivariate OLS regression is equivalent to a bunch of univariate OLS regressions for each dependent variable, but in the TLS case it is not so.

Comment: I do not know R, but still wanted to provide R snippets for future reference. There are many people here proficient in R. Please feel free to edit my snippets if needed! Thank you.

Comment: Nice post, but if I may ask what guarantees the fact that the vector $(0,\ldots, 1, \ldots, \beta_k)$ lies in the hyperplane?

Comment: @JohnK, I am not sure what exactly is unclear. As I wrote, let all $x_i$ be equal to zero apart from $x_k=1$. Then if you plug this into $y=\sum \beta_j x_j$, you will get $y=\beta_k\cdot 1 = \beta_k$. So the point $(0,\ldots, 1, \ldots \beta_k)$ lies on the hyperplane defined by the equation $y=\sum \beta_j x_j$.

Comment: I seem to have misread that part but now it is clear. Thanks for the clarification too.

Comment: In R, you might prefer "eigen(cov(cbind(x, y)))\$vectors" over "prcomp(cbind(x, y))\$rotation" because the former is much faster for larger vectors.

Comment: There's a good answer over on SO for how to do the simple case in R: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27004546/2371031

Comment: All of this answer assumes that the error covariances are identical in all dimensions, right? Wouldn't this then, strictly speaking, only implement orthogonal distance regression, and not general TLS?

Comment: Why is it that it is only the first p eigenvectors that define the hyperplane we need? And aren't all of them orthogonal to one another? As in, why couldn't we have used the 2:p+1 eigenvectors as the basis for the hyperplane in question?

Comment: Can the closed form for $\hat{\mathbf{\beta}}_{\text{TLS}}$ be generalized to the weighted case? I.e. $\hat{\mathbf{\beta}}_{\text{TLS}} = \left( \mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{W}\mathbf{X} - \sigma_{p+1} \mathbf{I} \right)^{-1}\mathbf{X}^TW\mathbf{y}$?

Comment: Isn't this closed form solution not fully general for TLS? Wikipedia cites [*"As was shown in 1980 by Golub and Van Loan, the TLS problem does not have a solution in general"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_least_squares#Algebraic_point_of_view).

Comment: @amoeba, I don't think the solution of the TLS requires the data to be centered. The PCA requires this in order to assure the maximum variance directions. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Another reference I found useful is a review by Markovsky and Van Huffel, Signal Processing 87 (2007) 2283–2302, downloadable e.g. from https://people.duke.edu/~hpgavin/SystemID/References/Markovsky+VanHuffel-SP-2007.pdf

Answer (score 11):

Based on the naive GNU Octave implementation found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_least_squares), something like this might (grain of salt, it's late) work.

```
tls <- function(A, b){

  n <- ncol(A)
  C <- cbind(A, b)

  V <- svd(C)$v
  VAB <- V[1:n, (n+1):ncol(V)]
  VBB <- V[(n+1):nrow(V), (n+1):ncol(V)]
  return(-VAB/VBB)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`princomp` is running [principal component analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) instead of total least squares regression. As far as I know there is no R function nor package that does TLS; at most there is Deming regression in [MethComp](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MethComp/index.html).
Yet, please treat this as a suggestion that it is most likely not worth it.

Comment: I thought Deming in the MethComp package was TLS - what's the difference?

Comment: You must give it the ratio of errors on x and y; pure TLS optimises this.

Comment: @user88 can you give a reference for that? Judging from what I just read, standard TLS does assume the error variances to be known. From my understanding, Deming regression is just TLS in 2D, i.e., a special case of TLS.

Comment: For fitting a line or hyperplane through points, principal component analysis is mathematically equivalent to total least squares. For details, see H. Späth: "Orthogonal least squares fitting with linear manifolds." Numerische Mathematik, 48
(1986), pp. 441–445. This paper also presents another method, that is, however, computationally much less efficient. For an experimental runtime comparison of both methods, see section 2.4 of https://www.ipol.im/pub/art/2017/208/