# Introductory references about total least squares

Tags: regression, references, least-squares, total-least-squares

I am an engineering student and I've been recently told about the Total Least Square (TLS) method. I am interested in applying it to topographic measurements and in comparing the results with the ordinary least squares (OLS) solution.

I've been searching a lot but I couldn't find any tutorial about TLS. I am familiar with OLS but not with TLS practical applications. Can anybody recommend me some book, paper or any guide so I can learn to apply this method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to perform orthogonal regression (total least squares) via PCA?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13152/how-to-perform-orthogonal-regression-total-least-squares-via-pca)

Comment: I think that the explanation of TLS you seek is likely to be found in [the link provided by @amoeba](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13152/how-to-perform-orthogonal-regression-total-least-squares-via-pca), in which case this question is essentially a duplicate. *However*, you do request for a "book, paper or guide" - which suggests this might be a request for references, rather than a request for explanation. If the latter, then I do not believe this is a duplicate.

Comment: If you're primarily interested in seeking references, I suggest you (i) edit the title of the post to include something like "Introductory references about..." and (ii) include the `[references]` tag.

Comment: Good point, @Silverfish.