# Confidence/prediction intervals for total least squares regression

Tags: r, regression, confidence-interval, prediction-interval, total-least-squares

I am learning the ropes of total least squares regression and I found this thread [How to perform orthogonal regression (total least squares) via PCA?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13152) where the answer by @amoeba, together with some R code, is just spectacular.

However, unlike a vanilla linear regression, I am unsure about how to calculate the confidence interval of my prediction.

Can anyone help and, if possible, provide some R code?

Comment: You might be interested in package `deming`. However, it doesn't calculate confidence intervals for predictions (only for coefficients). You can probably use bootstrap techniques to get what you need.