# Principal component regression of y on x and x on y

Tags: regression, pca, linear-model

If we regress $y$ on $x$, the regression coefficient is $\beta_1=\frac{cov(x,y)}{var(x)}$ and if we regression $x$ on $y$, the coefficient is $\beta_2=\frac{cov(x,y)}{var(y)}$. If we want to draw these two fitted lines on the same $(y-x)$ coordinates we know that the fitted line of regression $x$ on $y$ will be steeper. I have learned a potential way to solve this problem is to run PCR (Principal component regression). But why is it the case? And is that possible to derive that mathematically?

Comment: Of possible interest: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/136597/930.

Comment: To what does "this problem" refer?