# Can PC1 explain more than 90% of variance?

Tags: pca

I've been running some analysis using morphological data. However, when I run a PCA, PC1 explains more than 90% of variance. I'm not sure if this is possible. If not, what should I need to do?
[image]

Comment: Have you standardized your variables before the PCA?

Comment: I did it few minutes ago, but still PC1 explains around 90%. I'm not sure it is correct.

Comment: just because no one has said it explicitly: this is really good news for you, in terms of there being a simple way to examine your problem (assuming everything is correct; as Serdash mentioned, if you haven't subtracted your mean from each column that could be manifesting itself here).

Comment: This is more of a subject matter question than a statistics question?

Whether this is plausible or not really depends on the field and the specific data. I could imagine height and weight going up in near lockstep in some data set hence PC1 explains almost all the variation. I could also imagine a height, hair color, BMI dataset where there's a lot of unrelated variation among all the features.

Comment: Sure it can. It is also possible to produce an example where it totally explains the variance in the sample.

Comment: Often this arises when examining data that have a common source of variation.  For morphological data, that common source is *overall size.*  In many such applications that's of little interest.  What you might prefer to do, if your intent is to study variation in *shape,* is to perform PCA on *standardized* variables.  But since you haven't explained why you are doing PCA, there's little we can add in terms of recommendations.

Comment: I mean, if you take the equation of a line in any direction in a k-dimensional space, then randomly generate a bunch of points that fall on that line, then PC1 will explain 100% of the variance. So yeah, of course it's *possible*.

Answer (score 20):

Certainly that can happen. Below is a simulated example in R with just two original variables. As long as they are strongly enough correlated, they can very well be summarized by the projection to a single line, which means that the first principal component explains an arbitrarily large proportion of total variance:

```
library(MASS)
set.seed(1)
dataset <- mvrnorm(1000,c(0,0),cbind(c(1,0.99),c(0.99,1)))
summary(prcomp(dataset))
plot(dataset,las=1,pch=19,cex=0.6)
```

Output:

```
Importance of components:
                         PC1     PC2
Standard deviation     1.460 0.10400
Proportion of Variance 0.995 0.00505
Cumulative Proportion  0.995 1.00000
```

[image: scatterplot]

I very much recommend [Making sense of principal component analysis, eigenvectors & eigenvalues](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/2691/1352).

Answer (score 9):

In case you need a non-simulated example: I did `help.search("morpholog", agrep = FALSE)` to find morphological data sets in the set of R packages I happen to have installed on my system.  A useful one is `ade4::tortues`, a data set on 48 painted turtles from Jolicoeur and Mosimann 1960.

`long`, `larg`, and `haut` are the length, width, and height of the turtles in mm; because they're all measured in the same units, it shouldn't be necessary to scale the variable before/while computing principal components.

```r
library(ade4)
## column 4 is sex
pairs(tortues[,1:3], col = tortues[,4], gap = 0)
summary(prcomp(tortues[,1:3]))
```

PC1 has 98% of the variance. (Jolicoeur and Mosimann get 97.61%; I get 97.16% if I set `scale= TRUE`; haven't checked for other issues [transcription errors etc.]).

```
Importance of components:
                           PC1     PC2     PC3
Standard deviation     25.3100 2.40272 2.26449
Proportion of Variance  0.9833 0.00886 0.00787
Cumulative Proportion   0.9833 0.99213 1.00000
```

### [image]

Jolicoeur, P. and Mosimann, J. E. (1960) Size and shape variation
in the painted turtle. A principal component analysis. *Growth*,
*24*, 339-354.

Comment: +1. Maybe add that `long` is the turtle's length, `larg` its width, and `haut` its height, all in millimeters?

Answer (score 5):

Let $S \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times p}$ be the sample covariance matrix (which equals to $X'X$ for centered and intercept-free design matrix $X$), and $\lambda_1 \geq \lambda_2 \geq \cdots \geq \lambda_p \geq 0$ be all the non-negative eigenvalues of $S$, then the total variation percentage explained by the first $k$ PCs is given by
\begin{align}
p_k = \frac{\sum_{j = 1}^k \lambda_j}{\sum_{j = 1}^p \lambda_j}, \; k = 1, 2, \ldots, p.
\end{align}
In particular, the total variation percentage explained by the first PC is
\begin{align}
p_1 = \frac{\lambda_1}{\sum_{j = 1}^p\lambda_j}. \tag{1}
\end{align}
In view of $(1)$, theoretically there are no upper bounds that are strictly less than $1$ for $p_1$.  In other words, there exists $X$ such that $p_1$ can be arbitrarily close to $1$. For example, any design matrix $X$ in the form of $(2)$ below satisfies that its first PC explains $1 - \varepsilon$ total variation:
\begin{align}
X = U\begin{bmatrix}
\operatorname{diag}(\sqrt{1 - \varepsilon}, c, \ldots, c) \\
0 
\end{bmatrix}V', \tag{2}
\end{align}
where $c = \frac{\sqrt{\varepsilon}}{\sqrt{p - 1}}$, $U$ and $V$ are arbitrary order $n$ and order $p$ orthogonal matrices. Therefore, it is not surprising at all to observe cases such that $p_1 > 90\%$.

Comment: This is certainly technically correct but based on the way the question was framed may be too technical for the OP (but may be useful to later readers ...)